# TimePicker in @fluentui/react

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am a bt confused. I can import and use TimePicker from fleuntui/react. But there is no any documentation or any other information about one.

Is this a legacy, or experiments?

`import { TimePicker, ITimePickerProps } from "@fluentui/react";`

`"@fluentui/react": "8.49.4"`

Answer (score 0):

I was also checking about this for my current project. Apparently, it's a new addition to the fluent-ui library, but still need some work. You may look at the update on the [this github issue ticket for timepicker](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/issues/9545).